# "When I arrived at the Rome airport, a feeling of excitement flowed through me as I realised I am in the city of my dreams"

Tags: sentence-construction

Spot the mistake in the following sentence:

> When I arrived at the Rome airport, a feeling of excitement flowed through me as I realised I am in the city of my dreams.
>
> A. at the Rome airport.
> B. am
> C. flowed
> D. in the city of my dreams

I found two mistakes but sticking to the question there's only one. The usage of (the) is wrong but also (am) is wrong cause the whole thing happened in the past.. what do you think?

Comment: You explained why you think "am" is incorrect. Why do you think "the" is incorrect, which "the" are you talking about?

Comment: I mean  ( the Rome airport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that "the" can indicate "the only member of a category"<sup>1</sup>, and that this meaning of "the" applies to this sentence.  Where you are incorrect is analyzing what category "Rome airport" is in.  I would guess that you believe the category is "airports that exist", in which case there exist more than one airport in Rome, so "the" would be incorrect.  However, from context, the category is actually "airports I am using on my journey".  In this category, there is only one airport in Rome that the writer is using on their journey, so "the" is actually the correct article to use!

Options C and D are also perfectly correct.  So, the remaining option of B is the only incorrect option.  You are correct: the tense of "am" does not match the tense of "arrived".

<sup>1 - It can also indicate "the thing we both understand to be the topic of conversation", or "an object of extreme importance".</sup>

Comment: Thank you for explaining

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you mean "the Rome airport" is an error because there is more than one airport in Rome, I think that the "am" is the error because it is always wrong due to conflicting tenses, whereas "the Rome airport" means "the airport [on my flight] that is in Rome."

Comment: Thank you, Mary